# Is there an alternative maven repository for spring-data-neo4j to MavenCentral (it's broken)?

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, maven-central

This is related to this question: [Grails Neo4j - why is POM included as dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26980240/grails-zip-exception-error-when-including-dependency-and-running-test-app)

It appears that the file that's in the repository is corrupt, as I get the following error in Eclipse "neo4j-2.1.6.pom cannot be read or is not valid zip file".  It's basically the same error as above, as reported by Eclipse.  MavenCentral is reporting that the jar file is 24kb, yet apparently is should be much larger.

Is there an alternative repository to MavenCentral where builds of spring-data-neo4j can be downloaded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file is not broken on central, when I download it from here it comes down with size of 865743, and the zip file is valid:

http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|a%3A%22neo4j-server%22%20AND%20v%3A%222.1.6%22

Check the contents of the downloaded file, you'll likely find that your corporate firewall has blocked the download for some reason, and the file contains HTML.

Comment: Thanks - I've tried downloading from several locations and on several machines, but it's all the same.  What do you mean by "and the file contains HTML", is that a problem?

Comment: You're right - the cryptic stack trace message appears to simply mean that neo4j-2.1.6.pom is being included on the class path, and Grails is attempting to unzip the pom file itself.  Obviously it's not one, hence the error.